# Trying to install cProfile with pip and I'm getting an error

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, cprofile

So I've looked around everywhere for help on how to install cProfile and I've found nothing. When this usually happens I turn to pip and run the usual: 'pip install [module name]' but I'm getting the error: No matching distribution found for cprofile.

I have no idea how to install cProfile and I've looked everywhere. I rarely turn to StackOverflow and when I did I thoroughly searched it for a question like this.

Any help would be appreciated.

**Shorthand question:** How do I install cProfile?

Comment: cProfile should be part of the standard library.  What happens if you do `import cProfile` in the interpreter?

Comment: ImportError: No module named 'cprofile'

Comment: The import statement is case-sensitive - did you use a capital 'P'?, also what is the output of `python -c 'import sys;print sys.version; print sys.platform'` executed at the command prompt?

Answer (score 12):

Normally it is included in the Python's standard library. What Python version are you using? 
You can verify that with:

```
python -V
```

What pip version are you using? You can verify that with:

```
pip -V
```

and upgrade it with:

```
pip install -U pip
```

What is the output when you try to run cProfile in package mode directly through the bash, like:

```
python -m cProfile -o profile_output script.py
```

Morevover, the official documentation recommends using `profile` if `cProfile` is not available on your system, as they are mostly interchangeable. Please refer to [The Python Profilers Official Documentation.](https://docs.python.org/2/library/profile.html)

Comment: Python version is 3.5.1 and pip version is 8.1.1. My pip is latest and the result for the last one is no module named cprofile.

Comment: Are you really sure you are not messing up with the cases? `cprofile` and `cProfile` are two different things for the python interpreter.

Comment: I fixed the problem. So when I reinstalled Python (after reinstalling the OS) the download got messed up. I reinstalled it, this time checking the hash, and it worked. Also thank you to the users that told me about the module being case-sensitive. I was trying 'cprofile' instead of 'cProfile' which wasn't the problem but was good to know after!